# uefi: linux live cd/usb blackscreens

Tags: windows-8, boot, uefi, ubuntu-14.04, liveusb

I have a Medion Akoya P2310 D PC with Windows 8 pre-installed, and I have been trying to install Ubuntu alongside it as well as making a third partition for data storage. After struggling with UEFI for some time, I got the gParted (v0.19.1-4, x64) live-USB to boot, however after the grub menu it shows some logs and blackscreens (Strg-Alt-Del still works, though). The logs are normal gParted logs, as far as I know, except for "Windows is in hibernate mode"(which is wrong, Fast Boot is deactivated and I used restart), and the last log is "Waiting for /dev to be fully populated". Secure Boot is disabled, too, it is not in BIOS mode because windows 8 still boots without problems.
Trying Ubuntu (14.04, x64) does not work either, it blackscreens immediately after the grub menu, and using a live CD for gParted does the same.
Is this still a problem with UEFI?

Comment: For gParted to boot on a UEFI mainboard `Secure Boot`has to be disabled in the UEFI settings.

Comment: secure boot is disabled.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported/228069#228069) is of help to you from Ubuntu Stack Exchange.

Comment: thx, but I've already read this. I do everything it says there, still blackscreen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was (for Ubuntu at least) only a problem with the graphics driver. I usually use a hdmi and a vga screen (hdmi is the main one) and after reading [this](https://superuser.com/questions/611366/unable-to-try-or-install-ubuntu-12-04-and-above-64-bit-on-my-sony-vaio-which-inc?rq=1) post i tried booting with the vga one only, ubuntu suddenly worked fine.
Sorry for posting before doing proper research.